# What is the proper xpath for the listed options?

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I want to select an option, but I am not able to find the proper xpath of the given html tag below because it is not a select tag. How do I create a dynamic xpath of the aforementioned tag?

```
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-ContentPlaceHolder1_signup_CompanyType-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true"><span class="select2-selection__placeholder">Select an option</span></span>
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-ContentPlaceHolder1_signup_CompanyType-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="IT"><span class="select2-selection__clear" data-select2-id="11">×</span>IT</span>


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='select2-ContentPlaceHolder1_signup_CompanyType-container']")).click();
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='select2-ContentPlaceHolder1_signup_CompanyType-container']")).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@class='select2-search__field']"))).sendKeys("IT",Keys.ENTER);